# Parsing empty rows from MySQL table and output as html table without empty cells

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, if-statement

I have been trying to create a PHP function that can display a MySQL table as a HTML table using PHP.  So far I am able to output any table I choice, yet I am encountering a problem when the MySQL table contains empty rows, because empty cells result in the HTML tables.  My code is as such:

```
<?php
function getTABLE(){
$db_host = 'HOST.com';
$db_user = 'USER1';
$db_pwd = 'PASSWORD';
$database = 'testdb';
$table = 'FAQTable';  

 if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
     die("Can't connect to database");
 if (!mysql_select_db($database))
     die("Can't select database");

//// sending query and only result cell that are not NULL
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");

 if (!$result) {
    die("Query to show fields from table failed");
 }

$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);
echo "<h3><center>Table: {$table}</h3>";
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";

  //// printing table headers
 for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++){
     $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
     echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
 }

  //// printing table rows
  while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
    //// $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
    //// of $row to $cell variable
    foreach($row as $cell)
        echo "<td>$cell</td>";
     echo "</tr>";
 }
 print "</TABLE>";
 mysql_close();
 }

 print getTABLE();

?>
```

My dilemma is in the "printing table rows" section of the code.  I am hoping there is a way in the `while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))` to only accept rows that have values in them.  Any ideas?

I have already tried using the following lines with no luck:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE * IS NOT NULL");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM {$table} where answer IS NOT NULL or answer <>'' ");
$result = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$table} WHERE answer <> ""');
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE CHAR_LENGTH>0");   
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE val1 is <> '' "); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table} WHERE col1 is <> '' "); 

//// Outputs funky count in a separate table, but not the desired table with no empty cells
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(answer) FROM {$table} WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(answer)>0");   
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(answer) FROM {$table} WHERE LENGTH(answer)>0");   

$reslts = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
 while($row = mysql_fetch_row($reslts)){
     $empty_count = 0;
     $count = count($row);
      for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
           if($row[$i] === '' || $row[$i] === 'NULL')
              $empty_count++;
         $result = ($count);
  }
```

So Thanks To Paul Spiegal for helping with this PHP function that can output any MySQL Table into a HTML Table to be displayed on a website... The working function is as follows, just change the values for the variables to access any MySQL data:

```
function getTABLE(){
$db_host = 'www.host.com';
$db_user = 'user1';
$db_pwd = 'password';
$database = 'testdb';
$table = 'MyTable';  

if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
    die("Can't connect to database");
if (!mysql_select_db($database))
    die("Can't select database");

//// sending query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
 if (!$result) {
     die("Query to show fields from table failed");
 }
$fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

echo "<h3><center>Table: {$table}</h3>";
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";

//// printing table headers
 for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++){
     $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
     echo "<td>{$field->name}</td>";
 }

//// printing table rows
 while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    echo "<tr>";
        if (strlen(implode('', $row )) == 0) {
            continue;
       }else {
          foreach($row as $cell)
            echo "<td>$cell</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
 }
print "</TABLE>";
mysql_close();
}

print getTABLE();
```

Comment: What is an "empty row"? All fealds are NULL?

Comment: You know the table fields. So put a condition at where <field_name> is not null . Not * is not null.

Comment: Sorry about that, what I mean by an "empty row" is reffering to a row/record is a mysql table that is either NULL or, due to bad input error, is an empty space.

Comment: I should add, that this function is being designed to work on unknown 3rd party tables, where the records and fields are unknown, and loops are preformed to find that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using implode() function, you can combine all cells into one string. If that string is empty, you skip printing that row.

```php
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
    if (strlen(implode('', $row)) == 0) {
        continue; // skip this empty row
    } else {
        // TODO: print this row
    }
}
```

Comment: That is exactly the function that I needed and did know if it existed or what it was called.  Thank you so much.